# fire an action when you check a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

Here's my HTML, where I have two radio buttons. The default checked button is the "lease" button.

```
   <input 
    id="quotation_request_payment_option_lease"
    class="choose_payment_option"
    name="quotation_request[payment_option]"
    type="radio"
    value="lease"
    checked="checked">
   <input 
    id="quotation_request_payment_option_finance"
    class="choose_payment_option"
    name="quotation_request[payment_option]"
    type="radio"
    value="finance">
```

What I want to do is, when the lease button is checked, print "lease" to the console. And when "finance" is checked, print "finance" to the console.
I've tried various things to no avail.

This doesn't work:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[type=radio[name='quotation_request[payment_option]']').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'lease') {
        console.log("lease");
    }
    else if (this.value == 'finance') {
        console.log("finance");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: *"The default checked button is the "lease" button."* - Why do you have `checked="checked"` on *both* buttons?

Comment: that was a typo, I meant to only have checked="checked" on the lease button

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":radio[name='quotation_request[payment_option]']").change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'lease') {
      console.log("lease");
    } else if (this.value == 'finance') {
      console.log("finance");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="quotation_request_payment_option_lease" class="choose_payment_option" name="quotation_request[payment_option]" type="radio" value="lease" checked="checked"/>
<input id="quotation_request_payment_option_finance" class="choose_payment_option" name="quotation_request[payment_option]" type="radio" value="finance" />
```

1. Change your selector like above.
2. You can use `:radio` to select radio buttons

Comment: I tried that...no clue why it's not working if it works when you run the snippet here

Comment: interestingly enough, I don't see an error in my console, but it doesn't print lease and finance either

Comment: can you run in incognito mode?

Comment: just tried incognito mode on chrome, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You could write selected value to console directly. Use combination of single and double quotes for your CSS selector.

```js
$("input[type=radio][name='quotation_request[payment_option]'").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="quotation_request_payment_option_lease" class="choose_payment_option" name="quotation_request[payment_option]" type="radio" value="lease" checked="checked">
<input id="quotation_request_payment_option_finance" class="choose_payment_option" name="quotation_request[payment_option]" type="radio" value="finance" checked="checked">
```

Comment: But this applies to every radio button on the page, not just the ones with the specified name.

Comment: @nnnnnn, then use combinatiom of `'` and `"` to specify your CSS selector. Also you could use `[name^=quotation_request]` instead of `[name='quotation_request[payment_option]'`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the snippet to see the change in the console

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() { 
console.log( $(this).val() ); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input 
    id="quotation_request_payment_option_lease"
    class="choose_payment_option"
    name="quotation_request[payment_option]"
    type="radio"
    value="lease"
    checked="checked">
   <input 
    id="quotation_request_payment_option_finance"
    class="choose_payment_option"
    name="quotation_request[payment_option]"
    type="radio"
    value="finance"
    checked="checked">
```

Comment: But this would apply to *all* radio buttons on the page, not just the two with  `name="quotation_request[payment_option]"`. (Even if the OP currently has no other radios, they might in future.)

Answer (score 0):

In html checkbox add following trigger

```
onchange="myFunction(this)"
```

and in my Function

```
function myFunction(element)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

How about this

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is what is causing the issue try using:

```
$("input[name='quotation_request[payment_option]']").change(function() {
...
}
```

Comment: This would apply to *all* radio buttons on the page, not just the two with  `name="quotation_request[payment_option]"`. (Even if the OP currently has no other radios, they might in future.)

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer so it will now only affect radio buttons with the name "quotation_request[payment_option]"

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selector was wrong. It should be

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='quotation_request[payment_option]']").change(function(){    
    var value = $(this).val()    
    if(value == "lease") {    
        console.log(value);    
    } else if(value == "finance") {    
        console.log(value);    
    }
});
```

Comment: *"Your jquery object"* - I think you meant *selector*, not *object*. Why did you use `$(this).attr("value")` instead of `this.value`?